# What is the best middleware for the following architecture ? (Logs, ELK, Tableau)

Tags: logging, logstash, tableau-api, flume, bigdata

Please guys, can anyone propose a clear concept about the best middleware choice for this architecture, I'm in need to a **real time** middleware which can be very rich in its inputs, filters and must be capable to **directly** reach  Tableau software as output?
I'm lost between Logstash, Apache flume and their confusing output toward Tableau...

If someone has another concept, I'm all ears !
Thank you

[Proposed architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz3cd.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) applies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need an ETL to clean up and blend the data and then be used as an output to Tableau. If that's the case, you might want to go with [Pentaho Data Integration](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/) (aka Kettle), which is open source, and use the [TDE Output Plugin](https://github.com/cdeptula/tdeoutputplugin) to give you directly a Tableau Server Extraction as result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your proposition =) @astro11

Comment: I just found out that Pentaho Data Integration is not open source :\

Comment: It is. They have a business version, but you can download PDI for free if you check the link in my answer and if you want the source code, just go to their github. https://github.com/pentaho